# Repurpose APC UPS with Solar Panel as DC-AC Inverter, what changes needed

Tags: solar-energy, ups, solar-charge-controller

Firstly I have these items lying around,
330W 24V Solar Panel, APC Back-UPS Pro 1000VA/600W with dead battery

Wanted to see if I can repurpose this UPS circuitry to utilize solar panel during day time for light load in my house. If I can I assume I can just remove the battery connections and hook up the solar power there in the battery terminals.
Kindly let me know the right way, I can handle all home wiring as I have good experience with setting up minimal wiring for small condos but haven't done anything with circuitry but can do.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: IF the UPS uses 24V then it may work "as is". The startup current may cause problems. Iy you add a sma;; 24V battery (probably lead acid) it could help. even a "dead" battery with minimal effective capacity may work depending in what current it draws when the system is running. || 6 LiIon cells with a nominal 4.2 x 6 = 25.2V full charge voltage would work if you NEVER exceed 24V.. || 7 x LiIon cells at 24V = 3.42 V/cell = safe and at lower end of capacity range. 7 x 4.2V = 29.4V - IF PV panel voltage is NEVER above 28V then floating 7 x say 18650 cells across it may help.

Comment: Yes, UPS had two 12V batteries in series, so 24V is fine, but I checked the output voltage of solar panel in peak noon and it's giving nearly 39V, so little concerned if I can use without any charge controllers! Should I get a small basic solar charge controller of 20A ?

Comment: It's probably a 36V Vmp panel - 12V systems are often 18V and 24V systems 36V. (Count cells and multiply by 0.5V/cell as a rough guide). || A basic controller MAY NOT limit instantaneous voltage reliably under unloaded conditions. You'd want to check the specification and actual results. || Data sheet of same or similar UPS here https://www.apc.com/ca/en/product/BR1000MS/apc-backups-pro-1000va-600w-tower-120v-10x-nema-515r-outlets-sine-wave-avr-usb-type-a-+-c-ports-lcd-user-replaceable-battery/ || They do NOT say what Vin_bat_max is. Safe should be just under 30V for lead acid.

Comment: Adding a small float battery as above should stop overvoltage (probably :-) :-( ).  || It would be possible to make a simple overvoltage limiter. || Relay with voltage detector and a switched resistive load. || You could experiment with panel and see what load it takes to limit voltage to safe level. || Same but with MOSFET in place of relay also works.|| OR your mentioned controller IF Vout_max is GUARANTEED at no load.

Comment: Okay, i'll try that, thanks, and it's a 24V panel only, I checked its specifications and the peak voltage is till 42V for handling cloudy situations I think.